# Smartest way, to create multiplatform sites with SCSS?

Tags: css, sass

I am working on a Angular2 App, that got hundret of Sub Pages that use the Same Syntax. Only Content and Colors will Change.

Now i am thinking sience days, what the smartest way is to realize this from the SCSS Part. I work with "node-sass" and NPM Script. Ofc i can create each Platform a extra Script, that use another entrypoint. (Style1, Style2, Style3 etc...) But this sounds for me little dirty... And when i got allready 50 Versions ore more, then i need to change to much files for small changes in the Style files.

I am sure there are alot better ways, with "if" ore "each" (i am not familiar with this special scss functions)

I am very open to any suggestion.
Thanks for reading this! And best regards!

Comment: I would try to code it yourself, even if you think its not the best way. If you run into problems you can ask for help regarding the specific problem on here. If it works and you just want it reviewed then you can post your code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for troubleshooting/finding a better way.

Comment: Sorry, but I ask here which approach, or way, you would recommend me for it. If I now just go somehow and in 2 years to establish that everything is wrong and I have to start from anew, is not helped me very much ;)